When did Saddam Hussein kill 12,000 people in one day through the use of chemical weapons?
In 2023Mar, 20th anniversary of the invasion of Iraq led by the US & the UK and the 1st anniversary of the invasion of Ukraine by Russia, the AFP News Agency posted an interview with former UK Prime Minister, Tony Blair: Tony Blair: Putin can't use Iraq invasion as justification for Ukraine | AFP.
Blair stated:

The idea that removing a dictator [Saddam Hussein] who's brutalised his people, engaged in two regional wars, in breach of [multiple] UN resolutions and killed 12,000 people in one day through the use of chemical weapons [...]

When did Saddam Hussein kill 12,000 people in one day with chemical weapons?
The closest I found is Halabja massacre, but 3,200 - 5,000 people died on that day, not 12,000.

It turned out he could, mr. Blair...

The question itself creates a false impression. The fact that Saddam Hussein killed his own people with chemical weapons was not the reason for the invasion of Iraq. 3000 or 12000 deaths changes little. Nobody ever talked about intervening at the time. The situation changed after the invasion of Kuwait. But still it was not enough to consider his removal. The US led armies in the first war stopped their action right before causing Hussein's downfall.

He probably added the injured in that event. It's not uncommon for the victims (both dead and injured) to be referred to as casualties, and then someone assumes casualties means dead. I've seen it happen in fair number of other instances.

@FluidCode 'was not the reason for the invasion of Iraq' - I believe Tony was just pointing out how evil Saddam was compared to how Volodymyr Zelenskyy is. I have no idea how relevant that was. What do you suggest?

@BCLC why was this question edited from "Did" to "When"? Especially after it has been answered 18 days ago.

@BCLC I did not mean to judge the intention of the QA. I only explained the effect of such question on the reader. If I had to judge the intention of someone I would start from Tony Blair who is on these things very shrewd.

@BCLC Correction. My earlier comment was based on what I read when I received the email notification. I see that actually your comment refers directly to Tony Blair. In that case keep in mind that every declaration done by a politician of that level is carefully evaluated in advance by many spin doctors. They always consider how the public will understand and perceive the declaration.

@Ona Betteridge's law of headlines - i don't like yes/no questions anymore. same issue w/ those Y/N questions in 2023 United States Congress hearing on antisemitism. eg 'is calling for the genocide of jews bullying/harassment?' like if they're going to say 'no' it's like 'never' instead of 'not always.' even if reworded 'is calling necessarily?' w/c i'd probably do, i'd still follow up 'when does calling NOT constitute?' w/c stefanik didn't do. it can be a Y/N question if the answer to the question 'when?' is 'never' in w/c case the Y/N question is answered with 'no, never.'

@FluidCode Oh you mean you didn't realise in my initial revision I put 'Tony Blair' at the start, so you thought I was making the claim instead of that I was making the claim that Tony was making the claim?

He probably added the injured in that event. Wikipedia gives

Deaths    3,200–5,000
Injured   7,000–10,000

FWTW, an Al-Jazeera piece (by a Western author) similarly claims:

Some 5,000 people – mainly women and children – died on the day, and up to 12,000 have lost their lives since.

Whether that's fair math. YMMV. There are a few studies, incl. on children, finding that most survivors had significant impairments even decades later, but I've not been able to find one that estimated how much that shortened their lives.
Anyhow, the claim that 12,000 died on the spot is probably false.

Aside, but taped discussions between Saddam's inner circle showed that they had a fairly good estimate that "thousands" would die.

Long-term effects have been somewhat better studied on Iranian victims https://www.science.org/content/article/seeking-answers-iran-s-chemical-weapons-victims-time-runs-out
